# C# specific Point issue

Tags: c#

Alright I am slowly building a drawing program for fun and practice but I have a specific problem. Here is my code.

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
         Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
         Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
         g.DrawRectangle(p, start.X, start.Y, 20, 20);
    }
    Control control = (Control)sender;
    start = control.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
}
```

Now this draws a rectangle at 0, 0 on the panel on the first click as expected as a test because the start variable is after the if statement. The problem is the next clicks draw the rectangle way below where I clicked on the panel. If I click near the top of the panel it draws these rectangles near the bottom but it seems to atleast notice my mouse is in a different position each time.

If any of you could figure out the mistake I am making and explain it would help loads! thanks!

Comment: what is `start` here?

Comment: I am not sure, but my guess is that PointToScreen is indicating your mouse position relative to the screen but DrawRectangle is using points relative to the panel.  Try offsetting the points in start to account for your panel's position relative to the screen position 0,0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
start = control.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```

To this:

```
start = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
```

This fixes your immediate problem, but is your goal *really* to draw a rectangle at the position of your *last* click, and not current one?

Anyway, the issue you had is that the `x,y` co-ordinates you were saving were relative to the *screen*, not to the *control*

As per your comment, this draws a rectangle wherever you click (no need for the `start` variable anymore:

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawRectangle(p, e.X, e.Y, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh no I think I said my question wrong, I do want the rectangle to be where it is clicked currently. btw thanks for the code edit too

Comment: @Havion I've updated the answer to include the solution for drawing the rectangle at the current click position

Comment: Thank you a lot, I apologize for these silly mistakes I am still learning.

Comment: @Havion Everyone makes mistakes, no need to apologise :)